# How to show Javascript popup table when F1 is pressed, and disable Chrome's native Help page?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, jquery-events

I have created an ASP.Net Web Application and it has a JavaScript popup Table (namely `Aview2`). My task is to show this popup table when pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> button in my `TxtItemCode`. I have tried to show the popup table while pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> key, but it shows my popup table and Default Help page at the same time. I don't know how to disable this Default help page.

```js
function popupF1() {
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#TxtItemCode").keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.which ==112) {
        $("#Aview2").dialog("open");
    }
  });
});
```

My TextBox is as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtItemCode2" runat="server" Width="54px"onkeydown="popupF2()"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I avoid the default Help page? I have tried many types of coding for this situation (like using `window.event.keyCode = 0;` but i don't know where should i place the code) but i can not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With keydown and checking the keyCode, then preventDefault:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('keydown',function(ev){
            if(ev.keyCode==112){
                ev.preventDefault();
                $("#Aview2").dialog("open");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popupF1(event) {
        if(event.keyCode==112){
          $("#Aview2").dialog("open");
          return false; //or event.preventDefault()

        }
    }
</script>
```

You might need to have an event lister preventing the action on the whole document.

```
  $(document).on('keydown',function(event){
    if(event.keyCode==112){
      return false; //or event.preventDefault()
    }
  });
```

http://jsbin.com/foboyehiha/edit?html,js,console

Documentation:

https://api.jquery.com/ready/

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/